how do i fix the Method not allowed (GET) error in django version 5
i keep getting this error in logout.html in django everytime i go to it.
Here is the code for the logout.html:
<form method="post" action="{% url 'logout' %}"> {% csrf_token %} <button type="submit">logout</button></form>
here is my views.py code:
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
#from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login ,logout
from .forms import UserRegisterForm

# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username= form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created successfully for {username}')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form':form})
def logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login')

here is the urls.py code
path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),

i expected the site to look like this:
https://youtu.be/3aVqWaLjqS4?list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p&t=970
i am currently following the corey schafer youtube series as shared in the link

Although you don't seem to be using it that view you've built for the logout will basically go into an infinite recursion due to the function name being the same as the logout function you're calling.

thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat
i actually found the solution. Just do this:
in the users(views.py) add this code:
from django.contrib.auth import logout
def logout_view(request):
logout(request)
return render(request, 'users/logout.html)
and then in the main urls.py (the one created when you made your project) add this:
path('logout/', user_views.logout_views,name='logout')

Although that will work it will leave your site vulnerable to CSRF attacks where people can log your users out automatically. Actions like logging out should be done by a POST request which is exactly what has changed in the builtin view, you should do what the answers in the duplicate target to this question describe.
